# Blazor input: onblur throws, oninput works fine

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

```
<input type="text" @bind-value="Input1" @bind-value:event="oninput" />
<input type="text" @bind-value="Input2" @bind-value:event="onblur" />

@code
{
    public string Input1 { get; set; }
    public string Input2 { get; set; }
}
```

Text can be entered into the first input but as soon as the second input loses focus this exception is thrown.

> System.ArgumentException: Object of type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.FocusEventArgs' cannot be
> converted to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ChangeEventArgs'.

This feels like it's the framework and not me.  Any ideas?

I am using blazor server in .net 5.0.

Comment: Is there a reason to use onblur for binding? the default onchange would be fired anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy and test this code:

```
<div>@message</div>
<input type="text" @bind-value="Input1" @bind-value:event="oninput" />
<input type="text" @bind-value="Input2" @onblur="@((args) => message= "The bulr event was fired." )" />

@code
{
    private string message;
    public string Input1 { get; set; }
    public string Input2 { get; set; }

}
```

No issue.

When you use code like this:
`@bind-value="Input2" @bind-value:event="onblur"`

You actually tell the compiler that it should produce code that binds the input tag to the variable Input2, and that binding should happen when the `blur` event is invoked, but alas, the binding is performed when the 'change' event is invoked. In order to perform the binding the framework needs the `ChangeEventArgs` parameter, but it gets the `FocusEventArgs` parameter instead. What would you do if you were the framework. She treated you nicely. Only a small protestation.

Comment: So the point is that FocusEventArgs doesn't have a value property and so the abstraction over the DOM and JS is leaking.  Couldn't the framework just pull the value from behind the shadows or it totally ignorant of it?
I'd prefer if it produced a compile time warning in a code analyser or such.
Well in any case I suppose I can use oninput to get the (lack of) data and then capture onblur.  The actual problem I was trying to solve was I want to capture when a required field is skipped over (say entered into tabbed out of).